# R package issue: using dplyr and %>% function without depends statement

Tags: r

I'm relying heavily on the `dplyr::%>%` operator in my code. Now I get the error message

> Error in ParameterAdd(ticker.df) : could not find function "%>%"

when i want to call `ParameterAdd()` when `dplyr` is specified as `import` only in my `Description` file. Now I'm not completely sure, but I'm here forced to make it a `depend`?

Comment: Is it also being imported in the NAMESPACE file?

Comment: No the namespace file is clean of dplyr.